# Using select inner join in sql

Tags: sql

So I have 5 tables:

```
dane_osobowe:
(PK) id
imie

druzyna:
(PK) id
nazwa

gracz:
(PK) id
(FK) dane_osobowe
(FK) pozycja

kontrakt:
(PK) id
(FK) gracz
(FK) druzyna

pozycja:
(PK) id
nazwa
```

How can I chose all "gracz" from druzyna "1" which has "pozycja" 2?
I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM gracz AS gr 
INNER JOIN kontrakt AS kg
   ON gr.ID = kg.Gracz
INNER JOIN Druzyna AS d
   ON kg.Druzyna = d.ID
      WHERE d.ID = 1
INNER JOIN pozycja as poz
   ON poz.id = gracz.pozycja
      WHERE gracz.pozycja = 2
```

But it doesn't work :/ Somebody have idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Only one WHERE allowed, at the end. AND the two where conditions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM gracz AS gr 
INNER JOIN kontrakt AS kg
   ON gr.ID = kg.Gracz
INNER JOIN Druzyna AS d
   ON kg.Druzyna = d.ID
--Remove the where condition from here       
INNER JOIN pozycja as poz
   ON poz.id = gracz.pozycja
      WHERE gracz.pozycja = 2
and d.ID = 1   --Add it over here using "and"
```

ie, move all the where conditions together at the last.

EDIT:

To get the selected columns you can specify it like this:

```
SELECT d.id, gr.dane_osobowe, poz.nazwa
   FROM gracz AS gr 
INNER JOIN kontrakt AS kg
   ON gr.ID = kg.Gracz
INNER JOIN Druzyna AS d
   ON kg.Druzyna = d.ID
--Remove the where condition from here       
INNER JOIN pozycja as poz
   ON poz.id = gracz.pozycja
      WHERE gracz.pozycja = 2
and d.ID = 1   --Add it over here using "and"
```

Comment: Thanks :) But is there any way to show only "id", "dane_osobowe" (fk number) and "pozycja" (fk number)? Because now it show me everything from all tables :P

Comment: @Mateusz:- You can specify the column names whatever you want. I have updated my answer. Hope that helps